# python install.py -i not working

Tags: python

I recently tried to instal subterfuge but one of the steps included entering

```
python install.py -i
```

in my terminal, how ever when I did this it showed me this!

```
[errno 2] no such file or directory
```

Please help!

Comment: did you `cd` to the folder where install.py was placed?

Comment: I presume you are referring to the [man-middle-attack-thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) - [this](http://www.n1tr0g3n.com/?p=2751) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/subterfuge/) - please add the instructions you were on about to your question. You need to `cd` to the directory to get it to work. Then run `ls`. If you see install.py in the command output, you have found it and should be able to run `python install.py -i`. **DON'T DO ANYTHING STUPID, AND DO NOT EXPLOIT OTHERS**. @MadMike.

Answer (score 1):

The exact error you are seeing is relatively clear.  Python cannot find the file you are calling, `install.py`.

Quickly inspecting the [source](https://code.google.com/p/subterfuge/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk) for the project, there is no `install.py` in the latest trunk.  Thus, it is not too surprising that Python cannot find it.

Typically to install a package in python, you use the `setup.py` file and install it like so

```
python setup.py install
```

**note:  if installing to a system wide python interpreter, you will need to run as root or

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

** note 2:  The `-i` flag that you have used is intended to run a file and then drop to the interpreter after execution.  The flag goes *before* the file to execute:

```
python -i /path/to/pyfile
```